# Как в NavigationView повесить badge (иконку)?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

И использую в приложении `NavigationDrawer` из библиотеки поддержки

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

Вот `XML`

```
....

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_second"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer" />

....
```

Меню которое я устанавливаю вот

```
app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer"
```

вот так выглядит код `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_white"
        android:title="@string/inbox" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/about_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
            android:title="@string/about1" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

И в итоге выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу при попадании сообщений во входящие, чтоб это отмечалось в `NavigationDrawer`

Вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это могут делать разные библиотеки я выбрал [вот эту](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Она может цеплять бейджи куда угодно, но там нет ни одно примера как прицепить к `<item>`... Есть пример как цеплять в `XML`

```
<com.readystatesoftware.viewbadger.BadgeView
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="OK" />
```

Но все равно не пойму как прицепить его к `<item>`.

Может есть другие решения как это можно сделать?

Дебаг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    View menuItemView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_inbox));
    BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context, menuItemView);
    badge.setText("1");
    badge.show();

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я воспользовался [этой библиотекой](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

На гите полностью описано как ей пользоваться...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
NavigationView nv = ...;
View menuItemView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(nv.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_action_item));
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context, menuItemView);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

Comment: Точно Юрий я не подумал, что можно найти эту вью из кода... Только у меня почему не находит `menuItemView` я сделал дебаг и он показывает что после выполнения `View menuItemView = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_inbox);` этой команды `menuItemView = null`... Я думаю это наверное из за того, что `NavigationDrawer` закрыт и сам `item` как бы еще не создан... Но как с таком случае сделать что ли слушатель на открытие... ?

Comment: Я только что попробовал выполнить код при открытом `NavigationDrawer` и все равно возвращает `null` ... Прикрепил скрин к вопросу. Странно

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, обновил код. И да - надо это делать только после создания меню. В OnResume или при открытии левого меню, например.

Comment: Все равно возвращает `null`... Делаю дебаг открываю `NavigationView` запускаю метод и смотрю, что все равно `menuItemView = null`... Хотя вы мне как то подсказывали как добраться до `header`a и все работало... Вот так View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView textEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
        textEmail.setText(email);

Comment: C headerView все иначе - он не меню. Попробуйте код из ответа в onPrepareOptionsMenu вызвать.

Comment: Тоже самое) Не хочет работать) Я подумал, может сразу из меню вызвать `View menuItemView = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_inbox);` Но оно возвращает `MenuItem` а не `View`... Дополнил кусок кода в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте задать `actionView` в атрибутах элементов меню дровера. Что-нить простое типа textView

Comment: На item можно вроде повесить app:actionLayout и там уже добавить Badge к существующим  icon и textView. То есть actionLayout будет содержать ImageView (иконку) TextView (название меню) и Badge